# How to show random content every 15 minutes - php

Tags: php, random

Ok so i have a .txt file with a bunch of urls. I got a script that gets 1 of the lines randomly. I then included this into another page.

However I want the url to change every 15 minutes. So I'm guessing I'm gonna need to use a cron, however I'm not sure how I should put it all into place.

I found if you include a file, it's still going to give a random output so I'm guessing if I run the cron and the include file it's going to get messy.

So what I'm thinking is I have a script that randomly selects a url from my initial text file then it saves it to another .txt file and I include that file on the final page.

I just found this which is sort of in the right direction:
[Include php code within echo from a random text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035740/include-php-code-within-echo-from-a-random-text)

I'm not the best with writing php (can understand it perfectly) so all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> So what I'm thinking is I have a
> script that randomly selects a url
> from my initial text file then it
> saves it to another .txt file and I
> include that file on the final page.

That's pretty much what I would do.

To re-generate that file, though, you don't necessarily need a cron.

You could use the following idea :

- If the file has been modified less that 15 minutes ago (which you can find out using [**`filemtime()`**](http://fr.php.net/filemtime) and comparing it with [**`time()`**](https://www.php.net/time))

  - then, use what in the file
- else

  - re-generate the file, randomly choosing one URL from the big file
  - and use the newly generated file

This way, no need for a cron : the first user that arrives more than 15 minutes after the previous modification of the file will re-generate it, with a new URL.

Comment: Wow awesome idea! I'm gonna try implementing it now. Just gotta figure out how to delete the line once it's been used and I'm golden! Cheers man

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I sorta solved my own question:

```
    <?php

// load the file that contain thecode
$adfile = "urls.txt";
$ads = array();

// one line per code
$fh = fopen($adfile, "r");
while(!feof($fh)) {

  $line = fgets($fh, 10240);
  $line = trim($line);
  if($line != "") {
    $ads[] = $line;
  }
}

// randomly pick an code
$num = count($ads);
$idx = rand(0, $num-1);


$f = fopen("output.txt", "w"); 
fwrite($f, $ads[$idx]); 
fclose($f);
?>
```

However is there anyway I can delete the chosen line once it has been picked?

Comment: Which line do u want to delete? from the original urls.txt file or the output.txt file?

Comment: From the original file, urls.txt :)

Comment: (1) You should close file handle with `fclose()`, when it is not needed anymore. (2) You can use `file()` to read contents into an array, `$ads = file($adfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)`. (3) You can use `array_rand()` to pick random entry from an array, `$idx = array_rand($ads)`.

Comment: About deleting chosen line - there are 2 possibilities. If file is small (say, 2KB), you can go an easy way - `$adsToSave = $ads; unset($adsToSave[$idx]); file_put_contents($adfile, implode("\n", $adsToSave));`. If the file is large, it would be better to `fopen` the file, `fseek` to position before deleted line, `fwrite` rest of file (data after deleted line) and `ftruncate` the rest.

Comment: By the way, why don't you store contents of `$adfile` in already randomized order? That way, you could just read last line of it and truncate the file each time when you need to pick new line.